# Get non-authenticated user's details

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, crm, nimble

In some CRM applications, I've seen functionality which looks like it is pulling FaceBook feeds for private profiles of other users/customers... how is this done?  One example of this functionality is from Nimble: http://www.nimble.com/how-it-works/contact-management/

From everything I've read about the FaceBook API[s], they can only be used to pull information for the currently authenticated user or their friends, depending on the requested access.  Am I simply misunderstanding the product, and it's just a mock-up showing the logged-on user's/friend's information that wouldn't actually be useful in the context of a CRM application?  If not, I would like to develop a CRM tool to view the FaceBook details for any user, does anyone know where to start?  Does FaceBook allow businesses to pay to access that information?

Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: You can request some publicly available info if you know a user_id or username e.g https://graph.facebook.com/4 or https://graph.facebook.com/username - though some connections do require an access token

Comment: We would ideally need access to even private information... because otherwise there is no way to know what customers are saying about the company/products.  There's a lot of potentially valuable feedback there that the company could pay for if needed... or is this just not possible?

Comment: Look at the [searching the Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/). You'll be limited to just public information, but you can probably gleam sentiment from it.